# minimizing a CNF in python

Tags: optimization, sat, planning, cnf, pysat

I have tried to use minisat22 but it has no such functionallity.
im looking for an efficient algorithm to minimize a CNF formula implemented in python for minimizing a CNF. Im using pysat.formula but im open to other libraries as long as they are efficient and usable in python.